# How to apply multilevel groupby and filter top N records within each subgroup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, filtering

Input:
[image: Input]

I have an input DataFrame as shown above. The products in each category need to be grouped by the sum of their sales. From this we select the top N products(in this example,N=2) in each category and only those products from the respective categories should be displayed in the final output/dataFrame as shown below

Output:
[image: Output]

I could try creating loops and iterating. I was hoping there would be an elegant way to do this.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date':['07-08-2023','06-08-2023','08-08-2023','08-08-2023','07-08-2023','06-08-2023','06-08-2023','08-08-2023'],
             'Category':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
             'Products':['abc','xyz','abc','def','nop','hjk','qrs','qrs'],
             'Sales':[1,2,4,3,4,5,2,3]})
```

Comment: @Vitalizzare There can be repetition of products within each group. This is because the same product can get sold on different dates.  So ideally, I would like to view those products in each group which have contributed to sales significantly. So the top N products within each group should be selected by aggregating the sales value. But while displaying the dataframe, the products should be listed as they are along with the respective dates on which they were sold on. The earlier question doesn't involve the repetition of products within each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the top N products, then a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
N = 2
cols = ['Category', 'Products']

out = df.merge(df
   .groupby(cols, as_index=False)['Sales'].sum()
   .sort_values(by='Sales', ascending=False)
   .groupby('Category', as_index=False)
   [cols].head(N)
 )
```

Output:

```
         Date Category Products  Sales
0  07-08-2023        A      abc      1
1  08-08-2023        A      abc      4
2  08-08-2023        A      def      3
3  06-08-2023        B      hjk      5
4  06-08-2023        B      qrs      2
5  08-08-2023        B      qrs      3
```